# Создание подчиненной формы

Tags: база-данных, access

Здравствуйте. Обычно при создании и работе с подчиненными формами не возникает проблем. Но в данном случай что то не выходит. Необходимо создать форму для отчета работы сотрудника за день, которая будет выглядеть подобным образом: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально проблема была в создании формы в которой будет проставлено время(в левой части таблички). Решил ее, создав таблицу time с атрибутами(8:30;9:00 и т.д). Создал таблицы, связал, но подчиненная таблица заполняется отдельно.

[image: схема БД и структура таблиц]

и, не смотря на то что в подчиненной форме есть связь, атрибут key_time в таблице manager_report не заполняется
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выскакивает ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не нужно давать ссылки на внешние файлы, они быстро ломаются. Разместите схему БД прямо в вопросе. О том, как задать хороший вопрос по БД: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-sql

Comment: Убрал ссылку...